# Unable to use import and use MySqlOperator in Apache airflow

Tags: airflow, mysql-python, directed-acyclic-graphs

I can't seem to be able to import Mysql.
like trying to import using this
`from airflow.operators.mysql_operator import MySqlOperator`
I get this error
"Cannot find reference 'MySqlOperator' in 'mysql_operator.py' "

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are on version `2.0.0` or greater, the import would be:

```py
from airflow.providers.mysql.operators.mysql import MySqlOperator
```

Remember to install the [MySQL providers package](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers/packages-ref.html#apache-airflow-providers-mysql) first:

`pip install 'apache-airflow-providers-mysql'`

Here is an [example](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-mysql/stable/_modules/airflow/providers/mysql/example_dags/example_mysql.html) from the docs.

Comment: And If you are not on Airflow 2+ better upgrade NOW. Airflow 1.10 reached end-of-life in June 17th 2021 and it will no longer receive even critical security fixes. You can watch the discussion panel "Keep your airflow secure" from "just running" Airflow Summit 2021 https://www.crowdcast.io/e/airflowsummit2021/3  where we discussed it at length.